# monthly attendance of each student

Tags: sql-server-2008

this is my table i have.
here i have an attendance of students belongs to one section. daily attendance of one year.

```
   student_name     id       attendance       dates
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    abc             1         p             2015-12-29 11:58:29.143
    def             2         a             2015-12-28 11:58:29.143
    ghk             3         p             2015-12-27 11:58:29.143

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here my need to print like following

```
student_name  id  month   1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8 9 10....31
------------------------------------------------------------
abc          1    jan     p f p p p p p p...............
pqr          2    feb     p p p p p p p p ...........
```

please help me to write the script like this.
i have to print monthly attendance of every student each month

Comment: i'm still trying to take days  1 to 31 as columns

Comment: i thought pivot only helps my desire fruitful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following sql query to get the output in the format you asked:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT [Name]
  ,[Id]
  ,[attendance]
  ,DATENAME(M, [date])as [MonthValue]
  ,DAY([date]) as [DayValue]
FROM [students]) as stud
PIVOT
(
 MAX([attendance])
 FOR [DayValue] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10], [11], [12], [13], [14],[15], [16], [17], [18], [19],[20], [21], [22], [23], [24],[25], [26], [27], [28], [29],[30])
) AS PivotTable;
```